# Will USB devices slow down when using DP alternate mode?

Tags: displayport, usb-c

Just thinking, when I connect 4k@60Hz LCD to a laptop via USB-C and chain other devices via monitor's USB hub, should I expect slow down of throughput-hungry devices? I mean, with that resolution it's 12.54 Gbit/s for DP only and USB3.1 is supposed to be "just" 10Gbit/s, right? What's the trick?
(obviously I like the idea of connecting only one cable to my ultrabook, instead of two, HDMI being the other one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite old post, just noticed I never answered it even though I know the answer for quite a long time now. So, YES, the devices are slowed down. The screen I tested this with was LG 4k with USB-C connection and internal hub SLOWS DOWN TO 2.0 when you feed a picture via USB-C into it. When connected as a hub with extra USB 3.0 cable it stays USB3. It is absurd if you ask me, warning regarding such behavior should be noted with a large colorful label on the box instead of all that marketing bs which is usually present.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean, with that resolution it's 12.54 Gbit/s for DP only and USB3.1 is supposed to be "just" 10Gbit/s, right? What's the trick?

I see that you have an answer but not necessarily about "the trick".

USB-C ports and cables have four "super speed" (or SS) pairs or wires (or "lanes") that can be used for USB 3.x data or some alternate mode like DisplayPort.  These lanes can support up to 40 Gbps when used together on a short passive cable or long active cable, and when using a protocol that supports these speeds.  DP will support these speeds, as will Thunderbolt and USB4.  The maximum data allowed on these SS lines depends on the length and quality of the cable, and on the alt mode protocol on the SS lines.

DP can share bandwidth on these SS lines with Thunderbolt but not with USB 3.x.  USB4 is supposed to fix this, allowing USB to share SS lines with DP and TB data.  USB will use these SS data lines in pairs, it's 0, 2, or 4 data lanes. DP will use 1, 2 or 4 lanes, most often it uses 2 just because it leaves 2 for USB 3.x.

You may end up with a cable that is too long to support 40 Gbps, and instead supports only 24 Gbps.  That means 6.0 Gbps per lane.  You choose a video mode that requires 12.5 Gbps.  DP looks at the lanes it has, and the speed that they can handle.  6.0 + 6.0 equals only 12.0.  You need 12.5?  Okay then, I'm taking all 4 lanes.  No USB 3.x for you!

USB4 doesn't add to the bandwidth on the cable, it just allows more efficient use of it.  With 24 Gbps available, and 12.5 Gbps taken by DP, then that will leave 11.5 Gbps for USB on the shared SS lanes.  A longer cable might have less bandwidth, a shorter one might have more, but the max will still be 40 Gbps for any cable even with USB4.

I just realized in writing this that USB and other protocols seen on USB-C define "lanes" differently, which can be confusing.  USB calls a "lane" two pairs of SS lines.  DP considers each pair a "lane".  I went with the DP convention in my explanation.

I don't know if lowering the resolution on your display will give USB room on the cable.  My math is just an example so it may not help to change anything.

Oh, and I too feel your pain on the "marketing speak" used to sell electronics today.  What gets me is the term "Thunderbolt compatible".  What does that even mean?  It means nothing, absolutely nothing.